# Is there an Ionic pull down refresh spinner like Gmail App?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I know there is 'pull down to refresh' in ionic, but this pulls the view down.

I was looking to see if there's a spinner that pulls down **in front of** the current view, as happens in Android Gmail app

For Android it's called SwipeRefreshLayout

[image]

**An AngularJS Implementation**

AngularJS (not Angular 2+) implementation of *Pull to Refresh* in Material Design by Alireza Mirian
https://github.com/alirezamirian/angular-material-swipe-to-refresh

[**Demo**](https://alirezamirian.github.io/angular-material-swipe-to-refresh/demo/) - you'll need to use DevTools, and switch to Mobile mode for touch gestures on a PC
It's seems a bit janky, although it's the idea I was after but for Angular 2+

Comment: I just noticed, it's used in the Stack Exchange Android app too

Comment: You can check this out on the Ionic website http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionRefresher/

Comment: @BertCarremans I've seen that one, that's the one that pulls the whole view down

Comment: Gmail app's refresher spinner is an upper layer, maybe we can use [Loading Component](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#loading) as a simulation.

Comment: @Brian do you manage to implement this? It´s a cool feature, I also hate the view to move down

Comment: @MarBVI Hi. I held off of on learning Ionic 2. Wasn't sure if performance (speed) was good enough for widespread adoption. I'm not impressed with the Showcase apps I have seen so far. How has your experience been?

Comment: @Brian well...I´m an Angular fan, so my opinion might be a bit bias. I´ve developed several apps with Ionic 1 and I can really tell that Ionic 2 is far better. Not also in performance but the ecosystem to develop the apps. Angular 2 has tackled the performance issues AngularJs had, and that´s reflected in the apps performance. However, React Native is still a solid choice! Well, I´ll have to look further to achive this pull to refresh then!

Comment: @Brian sorry to disappoint you bro, but that's not Angular 2...the link you've posted is an AngularJs component

Comment: @MarBVI Thanks, I've updated the link description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is something on the Ionic 2 road map which may be released in beta 11. As they seem to be releasing the betas once every week or so I would guess this may be a couple of weeks away, but do not take my word for it!

[See this GitHub request](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5557).

Comment: Spot on, thanks. Looks like it's one that will be available in the coming months

Comment: I am also waiting...!

Comment: still waiting...

Comment: I'm not sure if that is coming anytime soon :(

Comment: The issue has been moved to the `ionic-v3` repo https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/issues/40

Answer (score 1):

Hmm that is a good question. I would just use a swipe gestures that triggers a function that changes the value of an ngDirective for example the ngShow directive and if the value is changed by the triggered function the div with the ngShow directive will be shown and there you can place the spinner icon

Comment: Hi. I havn't started to look at how to implement myself yet, best to see if it is a current component first. Also, as v2 is still in beta stage, these sort of things could be added to Requested Features. I'll have a look there, and see if it's already in the list